# Hidden Field value returns null when i access it from javascript function on the same page

Tags: javascript, json, hidden

**what i wrote in my aspx form ::**

```
     <%@ Page Title="Sector Composition" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/UIPages/ApexM.Master"
     AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Sector_Composition.aspx.cs" Inherits="Anonymous_Sector_Composition" %>

   <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
   <script type="text/javascript">


    var browserData = [];
    var versionsData = [];
    var chart;



    function OnPageLoad()
    {



        var oJSON_DataTable_DataHolder = document.getElementById("JSON_DataTable_DataHolder");

        var oJSON = eval("(" + oJSON_DataTable_DataHolder.value + ")");

        var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors;



        for (var i = 0; i < oJSON.TABLE[0].ROW.length; i++) {


            for (var j = 0; j < oJSON.TABLE[0].ROW[i].COL.length; j++) {



                browserData.push({
                    name: oJSON.TABLE[0].ROW[i].COL[1].DATA,
                    y: oJSON.TABLE[0].ROW[i].COL[2].DATA,
                    color: colors[i].color

                });

                versionsData.push({
                    name: oJSON.TABLE[0].ROW[i].COL[1].DATA,
                    y: oJSON.TABLE[0].ROW[i].COL[4].DATA,
                    color: colors[i].color
                });


            }
        }







        // Create the chart
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'pie'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Browser market share, April, 2011'
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Total percent market share'
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    shadow: false
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b>: ' + this.y + ' %';
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Browsers',
                data: browserData,
                size: '60%',
                dataLabels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return this.y > 5 ? this.point.name : null;
                    },
                    color: 'white',
                    distance: -30
                }
            }, {
                name: 'Versions',
                data: versionsData,
                innerSize: '60%',
                dataLabels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        // display only if larger than 1
                        return this.y > 1 ? '<b>' + this.point.name + ':</b> ' + this.y + '%' : null;
                    }
                }
            }]
        });


    }



   </script>


    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphContent" runat="Server">


   <div id="Container">

   </div>
     <div>

        <asp:HiddenField ID="JSON_DataTable_DataHolder"  runat="server" />

    </div>


  </asp:Content>
```

**In my Code behind :::**

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

    psp_Chart_Composition_MktCapTableAdapter composition = new psp_Chart_Composition_MktCapTableAdapter();

    DataTable compositions = composition.GetData();
    JSON_Class Object_JSON_Class = new JSON_Class();
    ///////// JSON String with Rows And Cols////////////////////////////
    JSON_DataTable_DataHolder.Value = Object_JSON_Class.JSON_DataTable(compositions);



   }
```

what is the problem with the code ?? i could not get the value of the hidden field in the javascript function. i have tried with function call window.onload= OnPageLoad; and also of a button onclientclick event.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
var oJSON_DataTable_DataHolder = document.getElementById("JSON_DataTable_DataHolder");
```

to

```
var oJSON_DataTable_DataHolder = document.getElementById("<%= JSON_DataTable_DataHolder.ClientID %>");
```

Comment: My crystal ball is on holiday right now. You will have to give some more infos what is not working. Any error messages in the console?

Comment: @zean If my answer is the solution for this problem then you should mark it accordingly. Otherwise you should edit the solution into your Question :)

Answer (score 0):

You may change the code:

```
var oJSON_DataTable_DataHolder = document.getElementById("JSON_DataTable_DataHolder");
```

to:

```
var oJSON_DataTable_DataHolder = document.getElementById("ctl00_cphContent_JSON_DataTable_DataHolder");
```